# View-tree, view-state and how to visually examine them after every single request

Tags: jsf

I'm newbie in JSF technology so I hope someone can explain to me some obscure points. So here are several matters that I'm looking for clear answers:
1. Does view-tree represent the **view-state** of all JSF components that are present in single facelet(.xhtml) page ?
2. Is view-state only meant for "h:form" because I only see it as hidden input for "h:form" but not any other tags?
3. Basically, one facelet page will have one view-tree associated with it and that view-tree holds view-states of all JSF components in that facelet page, is that right?
4. How to visually examine view-tree, view-state after single request (either initial or postback request)?

Comment: 4. place `<ui:debug hotkey="x" />` in page and from browser do ctrl+x

Comment: Thanks very much, how about 1, 2 and 3 can you explain?